# Epic WIT is not present after import with witadmin in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs

Because I have an older Scrum process template, in the update of TFS I did not get the Epic work item type that you get when you create a new Team Project. This is a know issue and you can manually enable this work item type by adding it to the existing process template.

However, adding the work item type does not seem to work. I followed the instructions of Microsoft [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/09/16/configuring-the-epics-for-upgraded-team-projects-in-team-foundation-server-tfs-2015/).

When I add the WIT, it goes without any problems. I get the nice message: "The work item type import has completed." I use for this the following command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>witadmin importwitd 
   /collection:"http://{tfsServerName}/tfs/{teamProjectCollection}" 
   /p:"{teamProject}" 
   /f:"C:\{localpath}\Scrum\WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\Epic.xml"
```

But when I try to retrieve the Epic work item type, I get the message that it does not exist. I get the following error message: `TF201077: The work item type Epic cannot be found. It may have been renamed or destroyed.` To retrieve the work item type I use the following command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>witadmin exportwitd     
    /collection:"http://{tfsServerName}/tfs/{teamProjectCollection}" 
    /p:"{teamProject}" /n:"Epic"
```

Why is the epic work item not added to TFS, while I get a message that the import is completed?

Comment: Are you sure that the `Epic.xml` file actually contained the Epic work item type?

Comment: I am very sure. This is the default scrum template downloaded to my local system. I have checked the content of the file.

Comment: Perhaps you need to [refresh cache](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44016699/196451).