# TFS 2017 cannot find new Work Item Type

Tags: tfs

I have just added a new work item type using the witadmin tool:

```
witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:"http://mytfsserver.com:8080/tfs/myprojcol" /p:"myproj" /f:"mywit.xml"
```

The import was successful with message:

```
The work item type import has completed.
```

I then proceeded to update the categories, referring the new WIT in the RequirementCategory:

```
witadmin.exe importcategories /collection:"http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/myprojcol" /p:"myproj" /f:"categories.xml"
```

I got an error response:

```
TF237059: The import of the category definition failed. In the type definition,
category Requirement Category refers to a work item type that does not exist mywit.
```

I tried to get the list of WITs from the server:

```
witadmin.exe listwitd /collection:"http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/myprojcol" /p:"myproj"
```

But my recently added WIT was not on the list.

I tried to remove it:

```
witadmin.exe destroywitd /collection:"http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/myprojcol" /p:"myproj" /n:"mywit"
```

And also get its definition:

```
witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:"http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/myprojcol" /p:"myproj" /f:"mywit.xml" /n:"mywit"
```

And got the same error response for both requests:

```
TF201077: The work item type mywit cannot be found. It may have been renamed or destroyed.
```

But when I opened TFS through web browser, I can create a new item based on the WIT that I have just added.

Is this a TFS bug? How can I make TFS recognize the new WIT that I have just added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a caching problem.

Try running:

```
witadmin.exe rebuildcache /collection:"http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/myprojcol"
```

Afterwards you should see your recently added WIT.