# Visual Studio Error: TF201077: The work item type cannot be found. It may have been renamed or destroyed

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

We recently did a re-org in Azure Devops Teams and Areas, and suddenly a few of us all had the same problem: In Visual Studio (we're using 2017), when we tried to add a work item to a Git commit, we received the error:

> TF201077: The work item type cannot be found. It may have been renamed or destroyed.

The work items are definitely present in AzDev, and if we tried to reference a work item from an old Team that didn't change, it worked fine. What can we do about this?

(Note: we figured it out but since this specific question was never asked, I'm documenting it here for others to hopefully quickly find in the future.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a caching issue in Visual Studio. Each of the following solutions worked for at least one person. Choose your favorite:

1. Restart Visual Studio.
2. If you don't want to restart VS and you have multiple local Git repos configured in Visual Studio, in Team Explorer, switch to another local repo, and then back to the one you are working in.
3. Untested but I assume [this would work too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44016699/184546) from a developer command prompt:

   ```
   witadmin.exe rebuildcache /collection:"http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs/myprojcol"
   ```

Now try adding the work item again.

Comment: in addition, i'd like to comment that this occurs when you create a new item while VS is opened. We've noticed that after migrate from on-premise to services.